# .htaccess mod_rewrite redirection between domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, redirect

I have two domains, cshen.ca and cshen.net, both point to the same place.

I'm trying to accomplish the following with mod_rewrite:

- **cshen.net** is 301 redirected to **cshen.ca**
- **www.cshen.net** or **www.cshen.ca** are both redirected to **cshen.ca**
- the path after the domain is preserved after being redirected, for example **www.cshen.net/foo/bar/** would be redirected to **cshen.ca/foo/bar/**

I've tried a variety of rules, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cshen\.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cshen.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This accomplishes the first two rules, but redirects everything back to the home page, and does not preserve the rest of the URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cshen\.net$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://cshen.ca/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Making a small change and adding a slash '/' to the RewriteRule preserves the rest of the URL, but only **www.cshen.ca** is being redirected. Neither **cshen.net** nor **www.cshen.net** are being redirected anywhere.

I've also tried [Apache's guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) and used this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cshen\.ca [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://cshen.ca/$1 [L,R]
```

I thought this would work, since it should redirect *any* url that isn't **cshen.ca**, however, like the second piece of code, it does nothing to **cshen.net** or **www.cshen.net**.

I've just about ran out of ideas of other things to try. I would appreciate it if someone could help out!

**Addendum:** in case it matters, I'm using WordPress's pretty URLs, and the rewrite rules for that are:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried putting my rules before and after the WordPress rules (when I put it before I'd of course add **RewriteEngine On** before my rules), doesn't make any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901079/htaccess-redirecting-domain-alias

Answer (score 0):

don't know how to edit, solved by placing the code from apache before WP's

must have forgotten to test this earlier.

Comment: If your question is no longer relevant then close/delete it.